# Laravel 4, PHP save every single Hashtag in a single DB Row

Tags: php, string, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to save hashtags to a database. At the moment they are saved in a single row with the image_id and the following format:

```
Hashtags:    #test bla #test #test

DB:    test,test,test
```

**What do I have to do to save every single hashtag in a single database row maintaining the correstpondig photo_id?**

Here is how I save the hashtags:

```
$hashtag = new Hashtag;

  $hashtag->photo_id = $photo->id;

      $hashtag_string = Input::get('hashtags');




        $str = $hashtag_string;

            preg_match_all('/#([^\s]+)/', $str, $matches);

        $hashtags_final = implode(',', $matches[1]);




$hashtag->hashtag = $hashtags_final;
$hashtag->save();
```

Comment: I think you should look at the Many-to-Many relationship feature.take a look here http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many

Comment: I first of all have to know how to save them...

Comment: After you've got each hashtag just do a `foreach` and put your db model save inside it

Comment: Can you show me, how that can be done please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your needs there is several solutions:

**First:**
you can loop through hashtags and save them with correct image_id. like this:

```
$hashtag_string = Input::get('hashtags');

preg_match_all('/#([^\s]+)/', $hashtag_string, $matches);

//looping through matched items in your $matches array
foreach($matches as $tag)
{
  $hashtag = new Hashtag();
  $hashtag->image_id = $photo->id;
  $hashtag->hashtag = $tag;
  $hashtag->save();
}
```

**Second:** create Many-to-Many type of relation between `Image` and `Hashtag` and use full power of it. You can find everything in the oficial docs on  [creating](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many) and [using](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models)